# Read a datestamped file from an FTP server everyday using Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am trying to read a date stamped file from an FTP server each day, at say 16:15.  In an attempt to understand how to do this I am trying to connect to an FTP server, once a minute and incementing the file number each time.

The code that I have so far written is:

```
private String readFtp = "quartz2://exchange/readFtp?cron=";
private String cronExpression = "1 * * * * ?";

private int i=0;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(readFtp+cronExpression).process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("Triggered the process");

            from(getFtpServerUrl())
                    .bean(RateServiceImpl.class, "update")
                    .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
        }
    });
}

private String getFtpServerUrl() {

    i++;
    System.out.println("Here with i=" + i);
    return String.format("ftp://%s:21/%s?username=%s&password=%s&fileName=%s", ftpServer, ftpPath, ftpUsername, ftpPassword, "rate"+i+".xml");
}
```

When I run this, it is printing `"Triggered the process"` once a minute.  It is also calling `getFtpServerUrl`.

It is not calling `RateServiceImpl.update`.  It is not logging `"Downloaded file ${file:name} complete."`.

- Am I going about this in the wrong way?
- Is there a simpler way to construct the fileName each minute?
- Why doesn't `RateServiceImpl.update` get called?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this the wrong way. To add routes from a processor, you need to add the routes to the `camelContext` and not using the parent class `RouteBuilder` which is wrong.

The ftp consumer has built in support for cron expressions, so you can configure it to run daily at 4:15 pm. And then you would need to use a file filter to filter the files it find, and only pick the file you want.

The filter is documented at

- http://camel.apache.org/file2

The cron a bit here as well

- http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html

And I wrote a blog about it

- http://www.davsclaus.com/2013/08/apache-camel-212-even-easier-cron.html